# Hypergeometric 2F1 with negative c

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I've got this hypergeometric series

$_2F_1 \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
a &-n \\ 
-a-n+1 & 
\end{array} ; 1\right]$

where $a,n>0$ and $a,n\in \mathbb{N}$

The problem is that $-a-n+1$ is negative in this case. So when I try to use Gauss's identity

$_2F_1 \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\ 
c & 
\end{array} ; 1\right] = \dfrac{\Gamma(c-a-b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}$

I give negative parameters to the $\Gamma$ function.

What other identity can I use?

I'm trying to find a closed form to this: $\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i}$

Wolfram Mathematica answered this as a closed form: $\frac{2^{-2 a} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (1-2 a)\right) \binom{a+n-1}{n} \Gamma (-a-n+1)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (-2 a-n+1)}$

But I would like to have a manual solution with proof.

This is how I got that hypergeometric series:

$\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i}$

$\dfrac{t_{i+1}}{t_{i}} = \frac{\binom{a+i+1-1}{i+1} \binom{a-i+n-2}{-i+n-1}}{\binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i}} = \frac{(a+i) (n-i)}{(i+1) (a-i+n-1)} = \frac{(a+i) (i-n)}{ (i-a-n+1)(i+1)}$

$\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i} = _2F_1 \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
a &-n \\ 
-a-n+1 & 
\end{array} ; 1\right]$

**UPDATE**

Thanks to David H, I got closer to the solution.

$\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i} = _2F_1 \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
a &-n \\ 
-a-n+1 & 
\end{array} ; 1\right]$

$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to0} \frac{\Gamma (-2 a-2 \epsilon +1) \Gamma (-a-n-\epsilon +1)}{\Gamma (-a-\epsilon +1) \Gamma (-2 a-n-2 \epsilon +1)} = \frac{4^{-a} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-a\right) \Gamma (-a-n+1)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (-2 a-n+1)}$

As you can see this result is close to the expected $\frac{2^{-2 a} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (1-2 a)\right) \binom{a+n-1}{n} \Gamma (-a-n+1)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (-2 a-n+1)}$ formula. But the $\binom{a+n-1}{n}$ factor is still missing and I don't really understand why.

Comment: What's wrong with giving negative parameters to the gamma function?

Comment: Because the gamma value for negative integers is infinity

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that $a$ is also an integer. I see your issue now. One solution is to let $a$ be an integer plus $\epsilon$ and then take the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ at the end of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0016/) to express the hypergeometric function as a Gegenbauer function, and [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/GegenbauerC3General/03/01/01/0002/) which gives the value of the Gegenbauer function evaluated at $1$, the hypergeometric function in question may then be expressed as a ratio of gamma functions whose arguments are each positive integers. These can be reorganized into binomial terms for a compact final expression:

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(a,-n;1-a-n;1\right)}
&=\frac{n!}{(a)_{n}}C_{n}^{a}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(2a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(2a\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\binom{2a+n-1}{2a-1}}{\binom{a+n-1}{a-1}}.\\
\end{align}$$

There's likely a much more direct way to derive this without this absurd detour into exotic special functions, but maybe this response will tide you over until someone more knowledgeable in combinatorial comes around. =)

---

**Edit:**

Here's a much nicer way of evaluating the sum using beta function machinery.

$$\begin{align}
s{(a,n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{a+k-1}{k}\binom{a+n-k-1}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+k\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(k+1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+n-k\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(n-k+1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+k\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(k+1\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+n-k\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(n-k+1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(k+1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n-k+1\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+k\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(a+n-k\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\operatorname{B}{\left(a+k,a+n-k\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a+k-1}(1-t)^{a+n-k-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}t^{k}(1-t)^{n-k}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}\cdot1\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}^2\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\operatorname{B}{\left(a,a\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(2a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\\
&=\binom{2a+n-1}{2a-1}.~~\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: You're great! Yesterday I was browsing that collection of identities but I haven't found this one :)

Comment: But  the $\binom{a+n-1}{n}$ factor is still missing, maybe I'm doing something wrong at the beginning. Anyway your solution for this $_2F_1$ is ok

Comment: @balping Remember that by the symmetry of binomial coefficients, we have: $\binom{a+n-1}{n}=\binom{a+n-1}{(a+n-1)-n}=\binom{a+n-1}{a-1}$. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I think I've discovered my problem. The the first term of the sum must be 1. So $\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i} = _2F_1 \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
a &-n \\ 
-a-n+1 & 
\end{array} ; 1\right]$ is just not true. I'll post an update if I figured out the solution. But I think from this point I can do this alone. Once again thanks for all. I'll also accept your answer as solution

Comment: And also for $i=0$ the first term of the sum is $\binom{a+n-1}{n}$. So I only have to extract this. So now, my problem is solved. Thanks very much. I'll post a whole new answer with my clear solution because I think it can be difficult for others to understand what we were doing here

Comment: @balping Well whether or not you need it, I realized there is a *much* better way to evaluate the sum, and I felt compelled to post it because my first answer was really unenlightening. Cheers =)

Answer (score 2):

We may try to keep it simple.
Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {a-1+k\choose k} {a-1+n-k\choose n-k}.$$
It is immediately apparent that this is a convolution of two ordinary generating functions.
To see what they are re-write the sum as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {a-1+k\choose a-1} {a-1+n-k\choose a-1}.$$
By the Newton binomial this is a convolution of
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^a}$$
with itself, giving
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2a}}.$$
Extracting coefficients we obtain
$${n+2a-1\choose 2a-1} = {n+2a-1\choose n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here I post the full solution

The problem: we are looking for the closed form of this sum:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i}$

The first term of the sum for $i=0$ is $\binom{a+n-1}{n}$

The ratio two consecutive terms:

$\dfrac{t_{i+1}}{t_i} = \dfrac{P(i)}{Q(i)} = \dfrac{\binom{a+i}{i+1} \binom{a-i+n-2}{-i+n-1}}{\binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i}} = \dfrac{(a+i) (n-i)}{(i+1) (a-i+n-1)} = \dfrac{(i+a)(i-n)}{(i-a-n+1)(i+1)}$

So our hypergeometric series can be described this way:

$\, _2F_1(a,-n;-a-n+1;1)$

Using [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0016/) and [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/GegenbauerC3General/03/01/01/0002/) identities:

$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(a,-n;1-a-n;1\right)}
&=\frac{n!}{(a)_{n}}C_{n}^{a}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(2a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(2a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(2a\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\binom{2a+n-1}{2a-1}}{\binom{a+n-1}{a-1}}.\\
\end{align}$

The final solution:

$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{a+i-1}{i} \binom{a-i+n-1}{n-i} &= \binom{a+n-1}{n} \cdot \, _2F_1(a,-n;-a-n+1;1)\\
&= \binom{a+n-1}{n} \cdot  \dfrac{\binom{2a+n-1}{2a-1}}{\binom{a+n-1}{a-1}}\\
&=\binom{2a+n-1}{n}\end{align}$